# Difference between closures in loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

What is the difference between these functions? Why does the first one work and the second does not work as expected?

http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/x6pyg/   (this works)

http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/bv4em/ (and this is not)

I'm trying to loop over input elements and add onfocus events on them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
    var item = helpText[i];

    document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function() {
        showHelp(item.help);
    };
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your non-working example, when the anonymous function is called, `item` has the last value it held when the `for` loop finished executing.  That's because this variable belongs to the parent function that contains the `for` loop.

In your working example, you create a new function, pass in the current value of `item` like so:

```
function (help) {
            return function () {
                showHelp(help); // <-- This will be the value enclosed in this anonymous function
            };
        }(item.help); // <-- Calls an anonymous function passing in the current value
```

This creates a new closure around that value as it existed during that iteration.  When the anonymous function is called, it uses that local value.

Answer (score 2):

It is treated as:

```
var item;

for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
    item = helpText[i];

    document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function() {
        showHelp(item.help);
    };
}
```

The loop has finished before any focus callback fires and at that point `item` is the last item assigned.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy in fact.

In the first case you are passing item.help inside of the closure, which acts as a local copy. It's like a prisoner of its scope. What happens outside, nobody cares.

```
for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
        var item = helpText[i];
        document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function (help) {
            return function () {
                showHelp(help);
            };
        }(item.help);
    }
```

In the second one, there is no closure preserving the value of item, which means that when item is evaluated, it evaluates to its actual value, i.e.: the last element of the array, since the last loop of the for set its value to the last value of the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
    var item = helpText[i];
    document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function() {
      showHelp(item.help);
    }
  }
```